# How can we achieve iOS strobe rates of 120Hz - 240Hz

Tags: android, ios

Building an iOS and Android Application which will leverage iOS and Android camera flash.  We need to achieve 120hz - 240hz frequency.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

As for iOS, Perhaps you can get it done in the screen, but not in the flash LED. Such frequency would kill or greatly reduce it's life, so I don't think you can toggle it that fast without private apis.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you may want to think about building a small dedicated external LED flash that was meant to operate in that matter, using bluetooth LE to control the rate of fire.